# Atata - How to access hidden menu

Tags: c#, atata

I am new to Atata framework and am trying to access the below hidden navigation menu but was not succesfull

```
<li class="absoluteContainer">
                <span id="aboutTheProject" class="isUpperCase hasDropDownLinks">ABOUT THE PROJECT</span>
                <ul class="navBlockLinksAreaSubLinkDropDown verticalMenu hidden">
                    <li>
                        <a title="Link to 'Vision' page on this site" href="/Vision" class="isUpperCase menuLink">Vision</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a title="Link to 'Benefits' page on this site" href="/Benefits" class="isUpperCase menuLink">Benefits</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a title="Link to 'Route' page on this site" href="/Route" class="isUpperCase menuLink">Route</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</li>
```

Clicking on 'ABOUT THE PROJECT' makes the menu visible but Atata is unable to even click on it, although it is declared as a link or a label too. Tried a lot of options like below but no luck yet.

```
    //[FindById("aboutTheProject")]
    //[FindByClass("navBlockLinksAreaSubLinkDropDown verticalMenu hidden")]
    //[FindByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]")
    // > span#aboutTheProject.isUpperCase.hasDropDownLinks
    //[FindByCss("body > div.navBlock.headroom.gridContainer.navBlockLayout.headroom--top.headroom--not-bottom > div.navBlockLinksArea > ul > li.absoluteContainer")]
    //[FindByCss("body > div.navBlock.headroom.gridContainer.navBlockLayout.headroom--top.headroom--not-bottom > div.navBlockLinksArea > ul > li.absoluteContainer > ul", Visibility = Visibility.Hidden)]
    //[FindByLabel("ABOUT THE PROJECT")]
    //[FindByName("ABOUT THE PROJECT")]
    [FindById("aboutTheProject")]
    public Label<HomePage> AboutTheProject { get; private set; }
    //public LinkDelegate<HomePage, TOwner> AboutTheProject { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'ABOUT THE PROJECT' is `<span>` element. You should not use `Label` control for it as it works with `<label>` elements. You can take a look at control definition of the control class. For your case you can just use generic `Control` class:

```
[FindById("aboutTheProject")]
public Control<HomePage> AboutTheProject { get; private set; }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, your solution worked. I tried Text like below and it worked as well.

`public Text<TOwner> AboutTheProject { get; private set; }`